# Laravel 5 Auth returning 302 and raw login screen response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In my Auth I have:

```
class AuthController extends Controller {
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->registrar = $registrar;

    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}

public function checkSession()
{
    return 'test';
    if (!Auth::check()){
        return false;
    }
    //return Response::json(['guest' => Auth::guest()]);
}
}
```

Which is part of something to redirect a user back to the login screen automatically if their session has expired:

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(function checkSession() {
        $.get('/check-session', function (data) {
            if (data.guest) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

However it is not working. checkSession request returns nothing and comes back as a 302. Another request also occurs immediately afterwards which returns the source code for the login screen.

---

routes.php

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin']);
    Route::get('/logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogout']);
    Route::get('check-session', ['as' => 'session.check', 'uses' => 'AuthController@checkSession']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    ...

});
```

I have tried just putting it in the above group but it gives the same result.

Comment: Show us your routes please?

Comment: I'm guessing some filter is capturing that request and redirecting to another page.  If there is a filter on that route, please show the filter as well.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense.  In the function you are checking if someone is logged in but you have a filter on it which will only pass if someone is logged in.

Comment: @user3158900 I edited my post, now the user doesn't have to be logged in.

Comment: I added in the Auth constructor

Comment: It's still returning a 302?

Comment: @user3158900 If I comment out $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']); it works, but I think I need that for something?

Answer (score 4):

I did the following and it works:

```
$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['getLogout', 'checkSession']]);
```

Instead of:

```
$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
```